# Set hint size of EditText within TextInputLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I'm using an `EditText` wrapped in a `TextInputLayout`. Setting `textSize` of `EditText` programmatically works for the input text itself. However, it is not applied to the `EditText`'s hint text, which is shown when input is empty.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug? In case of the latter, is there a workaround?

To illustrate, here are snippets of my code:

`TextInputLayout` within a custom `View`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/default_password_hint"
    android:textColorHint="@color/background_gray">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Since I want to reuse the `View` with different text sizes, I pass text size through custom attribute `textSize`:

```
<declare-styleable name="PasswordInputField">
    <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="hint" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and apply it in my custom `View` in the following way:

```
if ( attrs != null )
{
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes( attrs, R.styleable.PasswordInputField, 0, 0 );
    try
    {
        String hint = ta.getString( R.styleable.PasswordInputField_hint );
        if ( hint != null )
        {
            passwordInputLayout.setHint( hint );
        }
            float textSize = ta.getDimensionPixelSize( R.styleable.PasswordInputField_textSize, 0 );
        if ( textSize > 0 )
        {
            passwordEditText.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize );
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ta.recycle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

In TextInput layout

```
                <TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_signup_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed_signup_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
                </TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: hi, this seems to be an appropriate solution for a static scenario. Can you relate your solution to my scenario where I need to set textSize dynamically (since they are passed via custom attributes to my custom view)?

Comment: With "programmatically" and "daynamically" I'm referring to Java Code, with "static" I'm referring to XML.

Comment: reffer static now

Comment: is there any way to use hintTextAppearance programmatically in java code instead of using it in xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting a size in the string recource.

For example:

```
<string name="edittext_hint"><font size="15">Hint here!</font></string>
```

then in your XML just write

```
android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
```

This will result in a smaller text for the hint but the original size for the input text.

Or like this:

```
MYEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (arg0.length() == 0) { 
                // No entered text so will show hint
                editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mHintTextSize);
            } else {
                editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mRealTextSize);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi, these are two clever approaches. Unfortunately, the second approach did not work as expected. While the text size change is triggered correctly and even the height of the edit text changes, the text size does not affect the hint text but only the input text.
The first approach is interesting too. However, with my custom view component, it is not possible to directly apply the hint text in XML if I want to use different texts and sizes in different scenarios. 
Can that approach be applied programmatically too?
I'm going to try to pass the complete layout via custom attributes now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this programmatically it's working for me

```
    TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(this);
    til.setHintTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

You can customize the **style** as i mention below...

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
    </style>

TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(this);
        til.setHint("hai);
        til.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextInputLayout);
```